# Can i create a custom url with apache (raspberry pi)?

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi

Currently I have apache2 running on my Raspberry Pi. To view my local server on other devices, I need to enter in the IP address.

Is it possible to change `10.0.0.X/index.html` url to something like `myappname/index.html`? Is this possible using apache?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an Apache Setting, I guess. You will have to configure your network router to route to the Pi's IP if another device request the name.

In my router, I can set fixed IP Adresses for devices identified by the MAC Number of each device. I can name the devices and then acces them like this: http:\raspberrypi\index.html